# How to access SSH of AWS EC2 Instance without keypair/pem file

Tags: amazon-ec2, bitnami, amazon-ami

My client had installed **AWS Marketplace Bitnami WordPress** and he do not have any .pem file & credentials associated with that EC2 instance. We need to change something in wp-config.php & .htaccess file. Now we are not able to do this.

I googled but not found anything fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I am posting an answer to my own question. As after 1-week discussion with AWS support they share an option to me where I can use my client's EC2 instance (that is not associated with any keypair/.pem file). They reset my setting and shared lines of code that I need to add in textarea under "View/Change User Data".

And this lines of code had user:password string. With those credentials, I connected to SSH and completed my job... :)

> Sorry for security reason I can not share the lines of code. But I answered my because I am sure this answer will help someone in future. Actually needy will get a hint from my answer (i.e. "View/Change User Data") and he/she can directly contact AWS Support.

Answer (score 8):

Hey not sure if this helps because you need to have the .pem file to be able to use this technique and it is not best practice but, you can set a password for root/user to ssh into that server. This is an example of how to ssh into root user:

1) Login into your instance with the .pem file 
2) Update
3) **sudo su** 
4) **cd /** (just incase)
5) Edit, **vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config** and edit or do the equivilent of uncommenting these lines: 
    **Port 22 

    PasswordAuthentication yes

    PermitRootLogin yes** 
6) Restart sshd service, **service sshd restart** or **systemctl restart sshd** or equivilent 
7) Set password, **passwd** 
8) Log out and log back in without .pem file **ssh root@12.345.67.890**

Comment: but my client did not have .pem file. Thanks for your reply. but i found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

run sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config look for "PasswordAuthentication No" and change it to "PasswordAuthentication Yes" then save the file and exit :wq

restart ssh with "sudo service sshd restart", logout & then connect to test if all is well.

Comment: Make sure Port 22 is uncommented out, but that's working +1. Restarted ssh with systemctl restart sshd

Answer (score 0):

In looking at [Get Started with Bitnami Applications in the AWS Marketplace](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/get-started-marketplace/#step-3-deploy-wordpress-on-an-aws-cloud-server), it appears that a **keypair** needs to be selected when launching the instance.

The article [No Keypair for Bitnami Wordpress Instance - WordPress - Bitnami Community](https://community.bitnami.com/t/no-keypair-for-bitnami-wordpress-instance/48081/3) suggests that you could use a plugin file manager to get a key onto the instance, but it is probably easier to launch a new instance and migrate the WordPress configuration across.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. As John mentioned, you need to select a valid keypair when creating the server. If you didn't the easiest thing you can do is to launch a new server and migrate the content of the current one to that one using the "All in One Migration" plugin of WordPress. More information about how to migrate the data here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-wordpress/

Comment: I know migration is the solution. But the client is not comfortable with that. Doesn't Amazon support such kind of thing where we can reset settings or reassign the .pem file to old(running/not new) instance?

Comment: @TanmayVats - no they can't.  There isn't a pem to reset.  When you create an instance on the console you have to select "I acknowledge that I have access to the selected private key file (mykey.pem), and that without this file, **I won't be able to log into my instance**".  The only way to do this is either the solution above or to create an AMI of the instance and create a new instance - with a key - from that AMI.